# Swap image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to add a rollover effect to some images in my menu.

The menu is currently a styled unordered list.

```
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li> <a href=""><img src="apple_faded.gif"></a></li>
  <li> <a href=""><img src="banana_faded.gif"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The list is generated dynamically via a loop. What I am trying to do is remove "_faded" part from the image name when I hover over this `<li>` and do it with jQuery.

I know it's possible, just don't know how.

---

UPDATE:

Here's the working solution:

```
$("#myMenu li").mouseover(function(){
    var image = $(this).find("img");
    image.attr("src", image.attr("src").replace("_faded", ""));
}).mouseout(function(){
    var image = $(this).find("img");
    image.attr("src", image.attr("src").replace(".gif", "_faded.gif"));
});
```

Comment: How far have you got? Split up the task in multiple small tasks, like: 1. Adding events; 2. Getting elements; 3. Replacing elements attribute values;

Answer (score 6):

Not foolproof, but here's a jQuery solution.

```
$('#myMenu li').hover(function() {
  var image = $(this).find('img:eq(0)');
  image.src = image.src.replace('_faded', '');
}, function() {
  var image = $(this).find('img:eq(0)');
  image.src = image.src.replace('.gif', '_faded.gif').;
});
```

You *do* know you can do this also with CSS? Just remove your images, give your menu items IDs, and you can set a background image on your `<li>`s:

```
#myMenu li#apple       { background: url('apple_faded.gif'); }
#myMenu li#apple:hover { background: url('apple.gif'); }

/* Do the same for the other elements */
```

Comment: just 'this.src' - dont create a jquery object

Comment: Just realized that it does swap when I roll over the image. I need it to be when I hover over entire LI...

Comment: This all looks right but I can't get it to work for the world.         $("#myMenu li").hover(function() {
    var image = $(this).find("img");
    image.attr("src") = image.attr("src").replace("_faded", "");
 }, function() {
    var image = $(this).find("img");
  image.attr("src") = image.attr("src").replace(".gif", "_faded.gif");
 });  I do have to use attr("src") because withpout it I can not even get an alert of the image's path...

Comment: $('#myMenu li').hover(function() {
  var image = $(this).find('img')[0];
  image.src = image.src.replace('_faded', '');
}, function() {
  var image = $(this).find('img')[0];
  image.src = image.src.replace('.gif', '_faded.gif').;
});

Comment: @Blender that still will not work! in this case the var image is a jquery object which does not have a src property. You need the dom object ref hence  var image = $(this).find('img')[0];

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myMenu img').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).toString().replace('_faded',''));
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).toString().replace('.gif','_faded.gif'));
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple actually. You would just use the `hover()` method in jQuery:

```
 $('img').hover(function()
 {
     $(this).prop('src', function(i, oldSrc)
     {
         return oldSrc.replace(/_faded/gi, '');
     });
 }, function()
 {
     $(this).prop('src', function(i, oldSrc)
     {
         return oldSrc.replace(/.gif/gi, '_faded.gif');
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will definetaly help:

style:

```
#menu1 {
background-image: url('apple_faded.gif');
}

#menu2 {
background-image: url('banana_faded.gif');
}
```

html:

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li id="menu1" onmouseover="this.style='background-image: url(apple.gif);'"> </li>
    <li id="menu2" onmouseover="this.style='background-image: url(banana.gif);'"> </li>
</ul>
```

It is not jQuery, it is JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string splitting and then some concatenation.

```
<body>


    <ul id="myMenu">
            <li><img src="apple_faded.gif"></li>
            <li><img src="banana_faded.gif"></li>
        </ul>
        <script>
        $('li img').mouseover(function(e) {
            var current = $(this);
            var name = current.attr('src');
            var original = name.split('_');
            var swap = original[0];
            var swapname = swap + '.gif';
            //alert(swapname);
            current.attr('src',swapname);
        });
        </script>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the list with javascript, you might want to see the .live() function, http://api.jquery.com/live/ , it will add an event on each new element of the list, for example,

```
$(".liElement img").live("mouseover", function(event) {
         //Do removal
});
```